# Register long press volume key listener

Tags: android-8.0-oreo

With great interest I read the article [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-oreo-volume-key-long-press/) about long press volume key listeners while the screen is off in Android Oreo but unfortunately it is not very detailed. Has anyone some more information about this feature?

How does this exactly work? Is the `onKeyLongPress` method from an Activity invoked (and does this mean that the activity has to be in foreground) or where do we have to register this listener (maybe in a service)? The article also noted that this feature is only available for system apps but I guess it would be possible to grant the permission via root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could understand from [commit diff](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5026936e49540449165fd5881231f8970a29ea91%5E%21/#F4) and CTS tests written [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/oreo-cts-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaSessionManagerTest.java#105), the system app should call `setOnVolumeKeyLongPressListener` API from `MediaSessionManager` in order to listen to volume key long press events. The `MediaSessionManager` system service can be obtained as usual:

> Instances of this class must be obtained using Context.getSystemService(Class) with the argument MediaSessionManager.class or Context.getSystemService(String) with the argument Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE.

Like other listeners, the instance from the class implementing `OnVolumeKeyLongPressListener` interface should be in memory to receive events. Activities in the foreground and running Services meet that criteria.

When the listener is no more required, the system app should call the same API but pass `null` as the listener parameter. Failing to do so could cause exceptions in the background if the reference is not valid anymore. Also, the system can hold only one listener at the time, if two system apps set two different listeners only the last one will be invoked.

The `"android.permission.SET_VOLUME_KEY_LONG_PRESS_LISTENER"` could be granted via root but remember that `setOnVolumeKeyLongPressListener` has the `@hide` annotation on it, third-party applications have to access it via Java Reflection.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Really nice answer thank you for this! Haven't tried to register it by now but I will leave a comment here after I did so.

Comment: No problem! I like to do analysis on AOSP code. I'm going to wait for your feedback. I couldn't try it myself because I'm not with any Android O device these days.

Comment: I published a working example [here](https://github.com/Cilenco/skipTrackLongPressVolume). If anyone has ideas to the notes under ToDo feel free to contact me.